# phpMyAdmin - PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have the memory limit set to 128M in php.ini and all I try to do is just upload a Excel 2007 sheet of size 130KB, which contains only 100 rows. The error message in apache log reads:

```
[Mon May 09 11:09:00 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.71] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Cell.php on line 155, referer: http://192.168.1.228/phpmyadmin/tbl_import.php?db=ddms&table=DRUG_STANDARD&token=5cafbefd7afc55b4c627e71ef8625b41
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally never tried to import from Excel, just a suggestion,why don't you first try to export to CVS first then import it to MySQL